# Добавить пробелы между словами, для того что бы строки стали одной длины. Java

Tags: java

У меня есть стихотворение, в котором каждая строка отличается друг от друга по длине.

Мне необходимо равномерно распределить пробелы между словами, для того что бы все строки стали одинаковой длины.

Для этого я сделал следующее:

1. разбил стихотворение на массив строк.
2. нашел самую длинную строку.
3. нашел кол-во пробелов в каждой строке.
4. нашел разницу каждой строки с длинной самой длинной, для того что бы знать сколько символов не хватает в каждой строке.

Я только начал изучать java, поэтому немного затрудняюсь сделать оставшийся шаг, а именно добавить к каждой строке известное кол-во пробелов.

Буду рад любой помощи.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // преобразуем поэму в массив строк
        String poem = (Poem.text);
        for (int i = 0; i < poem.length(); i++) {
            String[] words = poem.split("\n");
            int countNulls = 0;//счетчик пробелов
            int maxLength = 0;
            String longestWord = "";
            for (char element : words[i].toCharArray()) {
                if (element == ' ') countNulls++;
            }//посчитали пробелы
            for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (words[i].length() > maxLength) {
                    maxLength = words[i].length();
                    longestWord = words[i];
                } //нашли самый длинный элемент
            }
            int num = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                num = longestWord.length() - words[j].length();
                // нашли на сколько остальные строки меньше самой большой
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-class-repeat-method-in-java-with-examples/amp/

Comment: Что значит строка `String poem = (Poem.text);`, каким образом она "работает"?  Здесь нет никакого массива строк, то есть, вы считываете всю поэму в один `String`.  И затем разбиваете этот экземпляр на строки (а не слова): `String[] words = poem.split("\n");`.

Comment: Poem.text - это класс, в котором находится стихотворение.

Comment: Так Poem.text  возвращает массив или одну длинную строку?  В стихотворении каждое слово занимает одну строку?  Так даже Маяковский не писал.

Comment: Одну длинную строку.  static final String text =
                    "У лукоморья дуб зелёный,\n" +
                    "Златая цепь на дубе том.\n" +
                    "И днём и ночью кот учёный\n" +
                    "Всё ходит по цепи кругом.\n" +
                    "Идёт направо - песнь заводит,\n" +
                    "Налево - сказку говорит.\n" +